# How to solve Handshake failure in Jenkins pipeline while using a jar which calls an API

Tags: java, jenkins, ssl-certificate, jenkins-pipeline, java-7

I am trying to build a jenkins pipeline which will be automatically triggered by commit to git. In the pipeline, I am executing a .jar file which calls a REST API. The jenkins server is an already existing server (limited access by me). 
In the .jar file I am accepting all SSL certificate as

```
try {
      // Create a trust manager that does not validate certificate chains
      final TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] {
          new X509TrustManager() {
            public void checkClientTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
            }

            public void checkServerTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
            }

            public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                return new X509Certificate[0];
            }
          }
      };
```

and then installing it as

```
      System.setProperty("https.protocols", "SSLv3");
      final SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
      sslContext.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
```

The API call runs fine on my local system as well as in a freestyle project in the Jenkins server, but, when I try to create a pipeline that does this, it throws

> "Received fatal alert: handshake_failure"

While googling frantically, I ran

> openssl s_client -connect
>   myserver.com:443

on both my local machine and the Jenkins pipeline and both returned

> New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 Server public
>   key is 2048 bit Secure Renegotiation IS supported Compression: NONE
>   Expansion: NONE No ALPN negotiated SSL-Session:
>       Protocol  : TLSv1.2
>       Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
>       Session-ID: 7CAB0E15710F2218A5B35D7819970AE062FFAAC85EFA87C3A534DEB668A7DA71
>       Session-ID-ctx:
>       Master-Key: 88CA56C238E916226C7A13EC487069093E97540FD57B18814E43D2810FDDE046CC5E5B67E05A0155AD775019B7EAB824
>       Key-Arg   : None
>       PSK identity: None
>       PSK identity hint: None
>       SRP username: None
>       Start Time: 1536747840
>       Timeout   : 300 (sec)
>       Verify return code: 0 (ok)

My Jenkins server uses JDK 1.7 (the jar ran fine in a freestyle project)
Any help would be appreciated in solving this.

Comment: Are you sure that the JDK you're running your freestyle project with is the same as the one you're running the pipeline with (try executing `sh which java` as part of the pipeline)? This sounds like a cipher suite compatibility issue, since TLSv1.2 was [disabled in Java 1.7 for client connections](https://superuser.com/questions/747377/enable-tls-1-1-and-1-2-for-clients-on-java-7).

Comment: Yes, I am running the same JDK in both. I ran both with debug option and the change I could find is what you said. The cipher suite is different in both freestyle and pipeline. How to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

From your comment above it sounds like the issue you're running into is that for your pipeline build Java is running with a different set of configured cipher suites for some reason.

You should be able to solve this by calling your Java application with a couple additional command line options when executing it from your pipeline:

```
java -Ddeployment.security.SSLv3=true \
     -Ddeployment.security.TLSv1=true \
     -Ddeployment.security.TLSv1.1=true \
     -Ddeployment.security.TLSv1.2=true \
     -jar myapp.jar -whatever -other -flags -you -need
```